# Vite `server.base` leaves the paths unchanged (and broken)

Tags: reactjs, vite, reverse-proxy

I have a Vite React server behind a reverse proxy in a docker compose environment.

It can be accessed at `http://localhost/react/` which forwards to `http://localhost:1234/` of the Vite server.

The HTML page root is downloaded fine. However, javascript calls fail with 404 when trying to access the imports such as `http://localhost/@vite/client`. Of course it does, since this should be `http://localhost/react/@vite/client`.

Configuring server.base does not change much.

```js
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 1234,
    base: "/react/"
  }
})
```

I have tried a few variations of base, like `base: "http://localhost/react/"` or `base: "./"`, but invariably the request continues to try `http://localhost/@vite/client` without the base path.

Is this what the `server.base` config is intended for?
If not, how can we make it work behind a reverse proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the `vite.config.js` file: base goes **outside** of server object.

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: "/react/",
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 1234
  }
})
```